# Where can I find examples of absolutely detailed formal mathematical proofs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I know that many mathematical proofs omit many explanatory logical rules of inference and principles of deduction for the sake of conciseness (for example, most proofs refrain from expressing the use of modus ponens and universal generalization because their applications are "obvious and assumed"). Can anyone supply a webpage that contains a proof(s) that omits few (if any) logical details for pedantic reasons?

Comment: You could try to look for the key words "computer assisted proofs" or "formalized proofs" or peogramming languages such as Coq : given that these proofs are checked by a computer, they have to be fully formal

Comment: You might be interested in proof theory, where proofs are themselves mathematical objects (therefore, they're formal).

Comment: http://www.mizar.org/JFM/

Comment: As Max said, the most formal form of proof you can find is in computer assisted proofs. Mathematics isn't really formal and that's also one of its advantages.

Comment: Proof wiki such as https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Double_Negation_Elimination_implies_Law_of_Excluded_Middle  or for more formal proofs http://us.metamath.org/